# Prove properties of lists regarding the content

Tags: coq

pattern_1 generates a list filled with 1's. I'd like to prove that there's a 1 in certain, or all, positions in the list. My guess is I should somehow refer to the inner part of the generator function but no idea how to do it.
This is what I have so far:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint pattern_1 (lng:nat) : (list nat) :=
  match lng with
    0 => nil
    | S lng' => 1 :: (pattern_1 lng')
end.

Lemma item_nth0_is_1 : forall lng:nat, lng > 0 -> nth 0 (pattern_1 lng) 1 = 1.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction lng.
  trivial.
  intuition.
Qed.

Theorem item_nth_is_1 : forall lng n:nat, lng > n -> (nth n (pattern_1 lng) 1) = 1.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n as [| n' IH_n'].
  apply item_nth0_is_1.
  apply H.
```

At this point the proof state is:

```
1 subgoal
lng, n' : nat
H : lng > S n'
IH_n' : lng > n' -> nth n' (pattern_1 lng) 1 = 1
______________________________________(1/1)
nth (S n') (pattern_1 lng) 1 = 1
```

How can it be proved that if item n' is one, then item (S n') is also one? Is there a better approach than induction on lng?

Comment: A short proof: `induction lng; destruct n; firstorder.`  Notice that you should not introduce `n` because then you get a too weak induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your theorem, you'll notice that nth depends on "n" and "lng", however when you do induction only in "n", you'll get stuck once lng is fixed, thus never able to be destructed/evaluated. You can fix this, just generalizing "lng", so when you do induction on n, you can say that theorem is true for all "lng" :

```
Theorem item_nth_is_1' : forall lng n:nat, lng > n -> (nth n (pattern_1 lng) 1) = 1.
Proof.
  intros.
  generalize dependent lng.
  induction n as [| n' IH_n'].
    - intros.
      destruct lng.
        + trivial.
        + trivial.
     - intros.
      destruct lng.
      trivial.
      exact (IH_n' lng (le_S_n _ _ H)).
Qed.
```

Of course, you'll probably need more destructuring/rewriting to solve the goal. Fortunately, coq has a casual scheme to solve nat double inductions.

```
Theorem item_nth_is_1 : forall lng n:nat, lng > n -> (nth n (pattern_1 lng) 1) = 1.
Proof.
  intros.
  elim/@nat_double_ind : n/lng H.
  intros; by destruct n.
  intros; inversion H.
  intros; apply : (H (le_S_n _ _ H0)).
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very helpful.

Comment: Tiago, the line 'elim/@nat_double_ind : n/lng H.' is not accepted. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you included the proof engine ssrflect? In case not, just import the files from https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html.